# How to enable circular reference in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

greetings all
sometime in my app the logic forces me to use circular reference
and i want to know how to enable this configuration in spring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=49).

I would advice from the first option there. Circular dependencies are not a good sign and should be avoided. You can create a 3rd, helper class, for example.

The other two options are workarounds and will be harder to understand and debug later on.

Comment: Is ApplicationContextAware still the best way to resolve circular depedency issue?

Comment: I can across this article that lists bunch of ways to resolve circular dependency issues.

Comment: The link is dead now. Would have been helpful if you'd have copied the relevant parts.

Comment: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160413160641/http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=49) salvaged from the wayback machine

Answer (score 1):

Spring has no problems with circular references. `BeanA` can be wired with `BeanB`, and vice versa. You only get problems with circular references if you introduce them yourself in your code.

If you have a specific issue, please elaborate.

Comment: I have Dao1 and Dao2:
1-in Dao1 i autowire Dao2
2-in Dao2 i autowire Dao1
my logic forces my to this and i am getting the excpetion of BeanCurrentlyInCreation coz of circular refernce
and i want to allow this type of autowiring or do a workaround.

Comment: @sword101: Please add these details to the original question, with concrete examples.

Comment: @sword101 In that case you should probably move that logic up into your service layer, and autowire both daos into the Service.

Answer (score -1):

My solution for circular references splits objects into two, which share an interface. One will be the implementation, and the other will be a delegate. The implementation is initialized with a reference to the delegate and it injects the reverse dependency into the delegate in its init method.

By doing this, Spring will only see references pointing from the implementation towards the delegate. This won't work if any objects need to use the proxy in their initialization but that's probably a much easier problem to solve.

More info in my blog post here http://james.mega-global.com/2012/08/avoid-circular-references-in-spring-ioc/.