# Cyclic dependencies in Spring

Tags: spring, cycle

IF I have bean A which refer to bean B and bean B depends upon bean A. In this scenario spring throws ObjectCurrentlyInCreationException ,but how internally it happen and on which object it will throw this error.
For Eg:

```
<bean id='A'>
    <ref bean='B'>
</bean>



 <bean id='B'>
      <ref bean='A'>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254931/how-to-enable-circular-reference-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes A and B have default constructors (A(), B()), I believe everything should go well. Possible dupe of this question: [Circular dependency in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485347/circular-dependency-in-spring)

Comment: just wanted to know,in what scenario spring throws ObjectCurrentlyInCreationException

Answer (score 1):

This is typical example of Circular dependency in Spring. Spring can resolve circular dependencies through setter - injection. Objects are constructed before the setter methods are invoked. The default constructors are needed for both ( rather all the classes involved in circular dependency) classes in order to help Spring construct the empty objects before calling the setter methods